# Ruby:iOS: Find all elements in a screen with appium

Tags: ios, ruby, automation, cucumber, appium

I am trying to find all the elements in the screen in appium in a single cucumber step. Right now, I have a query that runs and fetches and stores values present in the SQL table and those values I compare with the elements present in the application by extracting the text. I use ruby and I am identifying each element with its id and writing `find_element(I'd: "").text` to get the text. This text I store in the variable and compare this to the original data I receive from the db. Now, this element is dynamic, which means it may or may not be there,the next time I run it. Also, there are a lot of elements in the screen and identifying each would be a tedious task and if suppose that identified element does not appear the test fails. I do not want to use `rescue false` since I wouldn't know what appeared and what has not.

I was thinking if implementation of logic that cucumber table uses would help me.

The cucumber table step looks like

`And then the page consists:
|Table|
|Cells|
|Row|`

This would verify all the elements in the screen whether I give the name of element or the Id of the element in the table .

Currently, I cannot call the variables that has the db values to the feature file that contains cucumber table? In this case, is there a way, to simulate this? By hardcoding the table in the step definition file?

I tried using the format 
`[:table],
[:Cell]`

But this doesn't appear to work. Any help is very much appreciated. I have tried a lot of things and I am not able to remember everything.

Incase of any information required, please mention in the comments, I would be happy to update what ever needed

Answer (score 0):

For now, Have proceeded with this logic. This will print the elements that are visible and the elements that are not visible.

```
arrays = [$array1, $array12, 'array3']
  arrays.each do |array|
    begin
      wait_true { exists { find_element(:xpath, "//*[@value='#{array}']") == true } }
      puts "we can verify '#{array}'"
    rescue
      puts "we could not verify '#{array}'"
      end
    end
end
```